# Cannot get data from document in cloud functions (return undefined)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a document with 2 fields: field1,field2 (changed name for simplicity).

From a cloud function, I am trying to get the value from field1. The functions is not a trigger for that specific document, and I get the value like this:

```
const user_collection = db.collection("user")
const photoName = user_collection.doc(userid).field1
```

However, the value I get in return in `undefined`. I tried with data() or get() methods, but I end up with error `...is not a function`. Can not find anything in docs or SO that helped me get the field value from the document.

Any suggestions on how to extract that field?

**EDIT:**

```
exports.onUserDeletion = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {

    const userid = user.uid
    const photoName = user_collection.doc(userid).photo    //<--- this is "undefined"
    const filePath = `user_photo/${photoName}`
    const file = bucket.file(filePath)

    console.log(`userid: ${userid} photoName: ${photoName} filePath: ${filePath} file: ${file}`)

    return highscore_collection.doc(userid).delete().then(user => {
        return user_collection.doc(userid).delete().then(user => {
            return file.delete()
        })
    })

})
```

[image]

Comment: add your cloud function and a screenshot of your database

Comment: Reading the documentation should help: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: @PeterHaddad I edited my question to add those.

Comment: how do you know its undefined? Console.log?

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee Yes, exactly. I edited in my whole function to my question with console.log() part too.

Comment: try console.log(user_collection.doc(userid)) and see what it says

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee I tried it, and I get this error when trying to print to console.log :  Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path. Path must be a non-empty string.

Comment: ah my bad. that's because you're calling this after deletion. the document ceases to exist once you delete it. do `user.photo` right inside the function instead of trying to load the document again

Comment: See my answer;. I've given an alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the following:

```
exports.deleteUser = functions.firestore.document('user/{userID}').onDelete((snap, context) => {
        const deletedValue = snap.data().photo;
});
```

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_deleted):

> You can also trigger a function when a document is deleted using the `onDelete()` function with a wildcard.

---

In your code, you are using an [`authentication trigger`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_deletion) that's why you cannot access `photo` field in your document.

From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserBuilder#onDelete):

> `onDelete`
>
> Event handler that fires every time a Firebase Authentication user is deleted.

The `onDelete()` has a parameter of type `UserRecord`. You can check here the properties of `UserRecord`:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.auth.UserRecord.html

Answer (score 1):

The user is already deleted. Which is why fetching it from the database doesn't work.

```
exports.onUserDeletion = functions.auth.user().onDelete((user) => {   
        const userid = user.uid
        const photoName = user.photo    //<--- this is "undefined"
        const filePath = `user_photo/${photoName}`
        const file = bucket.file(filePath)

        console.log(`userid: ${userid} photoName: ${photoName} filePath: ${filePath} file: ${file}`)

        return highscore_collection.doc(userid).delete().then(user => {
            return user_collection.doc(userid).delete().then(user => {
                return file.delete()
            })
        })

    })
```